# Screen reader isn't reading Korean and Russian

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I am working on an angular application, that has localisation implemented, it has a drop down that helps user select languages, NVDA the screen reader only reads english, Spanish( Espanol )... but doesn't read Korean nor Russian which is written in there native language, please Advise

NVDA identifies, reads english, Spanish without adding the aria-label tag even after adding the tag it doesn't work for Korean and Russian

Comment: You need to add the `lang` attribute to the container that uses a different language, can you put a fiddle together showing what isn't working (is it a component or the whole page for example) and then we can help you implement it correctly.

Comment: user has  a preferences pop up(this is a component)pop up has a dropdown of  which  helps the user to change the language ,which is defaulted to english-American, the other options like Spanish the display for this value is Espanol , portuguese  portugese  display value for that is Portuguese and for korean the display value is 한국어, for russian the display value is русский  ,As we can see the display values can be read in English it is reading and for korean and russian they arent in english it is only reading link and for russian too it reads link

Comment: So have you tried adding the relevant `lang` attribute to whatever contains the korean and russian text. The `lang` attribute can be added to a `<div>` so that just the contents is a different language and a screen reader will understand that and switch into a different language model. What most sites would do to make this easier, is spell the words in English if you are currently on the English version. (So if you chose russian the whole page text is then in russian including the language selection), this solves  a lot of issues with character sets etc.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5sxvre?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html i tried adding the lang attribute as advised but still there is no fix

Comment: No so it needs to be `<li lang="en">English</li>` and `<li lang="ko">한국어</li>` etc. [all the valid attribute values are here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)

Comment: Tried it isnt working

Comment: care to share the updated stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5sxvre?file=src/app/app.component.html, for now i modified the same code, let it speak up korean for now and if it works right i will make adjustments to read specofoc language selected

Comment: You aren't trying to do this with "Windows Speech API version 5" as your synthesizer in NVDA are you? For multiple languages you generally have to switch the synthesizer to "eSpeak NG" otherwise you have to have a whole page the same language or have different profiles that you switch to for different languages. I have a feeling this is unfamiliarity with how screen readers work. Also it is `lang="ko"` **not** `link="ko"` as you have done that both times.

Comment: yeh, I suspect this is a speech synth issue, rather than a markup issue. Screen Readers can't speak languages they don't have voices installed for

Comment: @Graham Ritchie How do i do that windows speech PI version 5 as my 'synthesizer'? i am using the latest version of NVDA, read the documentation it says  NVDA is bundled with eSpeak NG, a free, open-source, multi-lingual speech synthesizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is two fold, the first is that your HTML does not identify the languages as they change, the second is a possible unfamiliarity with the usage of a screen reader.

### Adding the `lang` attribute

To fix the first problem of identifying the language of a particular section is straight forward, we use the HTML `lang` attribute.

You will probably have used this on a whole document but you can use it on any sectional / flow content element such as a `<div>`, `<p>` etc. to signal to screen readers and assistive technology that the language has changed.

In certain screen readers this will then automatically switch to that language pack (if installed on the client computer).

There is a [list of the ISO language codes here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) that you can use.

#### Example HTML for the `lang` attribute in a list

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <a lang='en'>English</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a lang='ko'>한국어</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a lang='ru'>русский</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**aside** - please be aware that an anchor (`<a>`) should only be used if navigation takes place and should have a valid `href` attribute (not `href="#"`), this would probably be better as a `<select>`.

### Screen reader usage

Even with the above mark-up you may still have issues if the client screen reader does not support the given language.

In some screen readers this can be fixed by installing the relevant language packs on the OS.

For Windows it is "Settings" -> "Time & Language" -> "Language" -> "Add Language"

On other screen readers it is the actual synthesizer that needs to be changed.

In your case NVDA needs to use the "eSpeak NG" synthesizer for it to identify different languages correctly. (other synthesizers may work but I am unfamiliar with them, the default "Windows Speech API version 5" synthesizer does not switch languages automatically (it does for whole documents in a language if the language pack is installed, not for document fragments though))

To change the synthesizer "Windows Speech API version 5" to "eSpeak NG" you right click on the NVDA icon in the toolbar and go to "Preferences" -> "Synthesizer..." -> change the "synthesizer" drop down and press "ok".

If you update the synthesizer and update your HTML to use the `lang` attribute (not the `link` attribute as you kept putting in your example fiddles) a screen reader will identify the languages correctly.

### My Advice

Despite all of the above being a valid solve for your problem I would recommend that if your page language is English then all options are in English.

Then if someone chooses another language (Korean) you can then present all the options in that language (Korean).

Although this may seem like it would be less accessible most browsers offer an "auto translate" feature that will translate the menu correctly if it is all one language (make sure to declare the correct language for the page (`<html lang="en">`) as this is important).

It also means that screen reader users don't need to know how to change their synthesizer etc.

Finally it saves you having to add `lang` attributes to the list of options, making your markup cleaner.

**This is my personal advice not official guidance**

Comment: din't work for es for NVDA

Comment: did you change the synthesizer settings? If not then upgrade to latest NVDA as this does work but you must use the right synthesizer on NVDA to handle multiple languages.